# How to cast to a generic type using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, autofac

I can create a cast function generically like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Convert<IEnumerable<T>>(object input) {
    return (IEnumerable<T>) input; // this works
}
```

But say, I don't have T, but I have Type. How do I get this to work?:

```
// object is a List<int>, Type is typeof(int)
public object Convert(object input, Type type) {
    return IEnumerable<Type> input; // this does not work
}
```

Comment: Casting is a compile-time operation; reflection is for run-time analysis. It's really not clear what you're trying to do or why. Can you explain more?

Comment: ok, i see - i wonder if adding the word `enum` into the title might be of use? eg `How to cast to a generic enum type using reflection?`

Comment: "object is a List<int>, Type is typeof(int)" ??? What exactly do you expect to happen in converting a List to an int other than an error?

Comment: Well, if implemented correctly, I expect it not to error:). Sorry, I'm trying to write pseudo code here